# Using add with an empty register?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm looking at assembly code that looks like this:

```
addl   %eax, -8(%rbp)
```

I know the register %eax has a value in it, but -8(%rbp) has not been touched prior to this line. Am I to assume it is empty, and will just put the value of %eax + 0 into -8(%rbp)?

Comment: No. It has certainly been assigned previously, you need to look harder. It might have been written using a different pointer, e.g. relative to `rsp`. Note that memory is not typically zeroed, especially not stack which `rbp` frequently points to.

Answer (score 4):

As @Jester pointed out in the comments, it should have an assigned value somewhere before that line, otherwise you are looking at a potential undefined behavior.

Let's take into consideration the following C source codes and respective assembly outputs (compiled with GCC, no optimizations):

File **add_1_noinit.c**:

```
int main(void) {
        int a;

        return a += 1;
}
```

File **add_1_noinit.s** (gcc -O0 -S add_1_noinit.c):

```
... snip ...
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
... snip ...
```

As you can see, add_1_noinit.c does not initialize the variable **a**, leading to undefined behavior (the return value of **main()** is unknown).

Now let's look at the output of an initialized **a** variable:

File **add_1_init.c**:

```
int main(void) {
        int a = 0;

        return a += 1;
}
```

File **add_1_init.s** (gcc -O0 -S add_1_init.c):

```
... snip ...
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
        addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
... snip ...
```

As you can see, in this example we know what is the return value of **main()**, and the value **0** is set to the memory region pointed by **-4(%rbp)** before adding **1** to it.

Comment: So -8(%rbp) is not mentioned prior to that line, nor is there any reference using %rsp, however, there is an array pointer that is stored at -24(%rbp). Would -8(%rbp) store the 5th element in that array? I don't think this is correct because I thought the pointer would point to somewhere else in memory for the array. I'm at a complete loss.

Answer (score 2):

Generally in silicon stored bits only have two states 0 and 1, so even if you dont see code that set that register it is not "empty" it contains a pattern and the instruction will use that pattern, crash or correct execution.  Now in simulation of logic you can have three or more states for a bit 0,1,x  where anything anded with an x is x or anything orred with an x is x.  And in that case you can have an "empty" or at least uninitialized register.  Xes are like the plague they infect your simulation and eventually turn the whole thing to xes.  So you have to be very careful to always write before you read.  Including registers.

I am sure in this case though if that is valid code then at some point prior to that instruction rbp was written with a sane value.  Depending on how you are disassembling this or looking at this it could be some data pattern that you have disassembled as code.  Being x86 is difficult to impossible to correctly disassemble, so if this is diassembled code you have to assume some percentage can be or are wrong.  If this is just straight assembly from a compiler or written by hand then assuming it is not bad code then you are just not going far back enough in the code or calls that preceed this to see the register being written.

Note a register cannot be "empty" the bits will have a state, and for bit storage there isnt an empty state, just zero or or one.